# Unset in all sessions?

Tags: php, session

The answer is probably "no", but is it possible to unset a specific $_SESSION Variable in all current sessions? I mean all sessions of all people using the website. I use $_SESSION variables to cache database usage and want to "clear" cache whenever someone changes something in the database. This would be an awesome way to do that.

Comment: If you can access the session directory it's possible.

Comment: You could probably store some sort of tag along with your session (say `$_SESSION['cache_tag']`. If your data changes, change that tag. On your request, check that tag against your DB; if i't's different, pull new data.

Comment: Roemer, stop! Before you start putting this kind of logic into your application, ask yourself: why am I doing this? You may want to try a third-party solution to handle caching the data for you. I hear `memcache` can be useful. Or maybe just use the database. You won't want to have to go through the trouble of maintaining or upgrading your own home-grown solution. It sounds fun now but down the road, you'll hate your past self.

Comment: Haha, I always hate my past self ;) I love my present self, though. ;)

It is just for a very few variables, it is not something chronic, urgent, or very important. I will look into memcache. Thank you!